# Google App Engine Cloud Endpoints: OAuth2 won't work. Can't load api

Tags: javascript, security, google-app-engine

This is really confusing me. I have followed all the examples for adding authentication to endpoints listed [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js) . Unfortunately, whenever I deploy this to app engine, I get a 404 not found error when I try load the the oauth API using the line:

**gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', loadcallback);**

I just get a Javascript error with the message: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) **

I can't seem to fix this, and I can't call **gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get();**
However,

**gapi.auth.authorize**

works fine.
Any ideas? The Authorisation works correctly from Android.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Wow, it took me a long time to find but was something so silly. I'm going to leave the answer here in case anybody has a similar issue.

The problem stemmed from using a App Engine plugin generated "connected android" project. This starts off without Auth, then you follow the instructions to add Auth as linked above.

The trouble is that in the created index.html file, underneath the line `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=loadGapi">` there are specifications that are forcing the gapi.client.load to use your domain. Remove this code (everything in braces) so it looks just like:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=loadGapi">
</script>
```

However, now none of the previously working calls to gapi.client.load for your endpoint api's will work. To fix this, you need to specify they should use your URL like so:

`gapi.client.load('deviceinfoendpoint', 'v1', loadcallback, API_URL );`

Here API_URL is 'http://' + window.location.host + '/_ah/api';